# a:hover element works in IE only if I scroll the underneath page

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have a popup fixed window with a list of  elements in a list. See this page and move mouse over "WEBSHOP": http://109.72.95.174/astudio/sites/danydiop/taxonomy/term/31

In internet explorer 8, for some reason the  text in is highlighted only if I scroll the page.

In other words, the links remain white, if I move the mouse over them, but if I scroll the page below the fixed popup with the wheel, they change color.

Could you tell me why ?

thanks

**Update**:

## block-vocabindex-1 a:hover {

```
color:#231B5B;
```

}

Comment: Could you post your CSS, specifically with the a:hover, a:active, etc.?

Comment: @Evan Mulawski I've added it to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not enough clues, so try to add a rule to enforce haslayout e.g. `zoom: 1`